# Cannot find the setter for attribute 'android:text'

Tags: android, mvvm, android-databinding, android-livedata, mutablelivedata

I have:

```
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <data>
        <import type="android.view.View" />
        <variable name="vm" type="com.my.package.viewmodel.SplashActivityVM" />
    </data>

    <android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutCompat
        bla...>

        <TextView
            bla...
            android:text='@{vm.status}'
            bla... />
bla...
```

with activity.java:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { bla... }

private void observeStatus(SplashActivityVM viewModel) {
        viewModel.getStatus().observe(this, status -> {
            if (status != null) {
                mBinding.setVm(viewModel);
            } else { }
            mBinding.executePendingBindings();
        });
    }
```

and my ViewModel:

```
public class SplashActivityVM extends AndroidViewModel implements ViewModel {

    private final MutableLiveData<SplashState> mObservableStatus = new MutableLiveData<>();
    public MutableLiveData<SplashState> getStatus() { return mObservableStatus; }

    public SplashActivityVM(@NonNull Application application) { super(application); }

// bla...
```

and I received below error:

> msg:Cannot find the setter for attribute 'android:text' with parameter type
>   android.arch.lifecycle.MutableLiveData
>   on android.widget.TextView.

What's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

1. You need custom [binding adapter](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/binding-adapters) for your SplashState

   TextViewAdapters.kt

```
@BindingAdapter("android:text")
fun setText(view: TextView, state: SplashState) {
    view.text = state.toString()
}
```

2. Set [viewLifecycleOwner](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/architecture#livedata) to your data binding for livedata

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { bla... 

mBinding.setLifecycleOwner(this);
}
```

3. Remove observeStatus method, set VM to binding

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { bla... 

mBinding.setLifecycleOwner(this);
mBinding.setvm(viewModel);
}
```